# Renoir painting in the National Gallery (Melbourne) described in On the Beach

Tags: novel, art

In the classic novel *On the Beach* (1957, p. 178), Nevil Shute has two of his characters visit the National Gallery of Victoria in Melbourne (Australia).

> They turned from the exhibition. "Are you interested in paintings?"
> she asked. "Or are they just a bore?" "They're not a bore," he said.
> "I like them when they're full of color and don't try to teach you
> anything. There's a painter called Renoir, isn't there?" She nodded.
> "They've got some Renoirs here. Would you like to see them?" They went
> and found the French art, and he stood for some time before a painting
> of a river and a tree-shaded street beside it, with white houses and
> shops, very French and very colorful. "That's the kind of picture I
> like," he said. "I've got a lot of time for that."

Well, no, he doesn't, inasmuch as Melbourne will soon be enveloped in a radioactive cloud from the nuclear holocaust that has already wiped the Northern Hemisphere clean of human life. But that's beside the point. What was the painting?

Nevil Shute wrote many novels and he is known for inserting convincing details based on his own experience into them. Paul Hagl recently produced an [episode of Melbourne Reel Streets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BX1fAY-zYsM) [sic] in which he rephotographed the places where scenes in *On the Beach* were filmed in 1959, and pointed out that the film was remarkably faithful to the book, which often mentions particular streets and other place names. While I do not have ready access to the film, which I last saw many years ago, Hagl did not mention a Renoir and I don't think that this scene was used in the movie. If the painting is real, it would probably represent the novelist's taste, and so is of some interest.

The National Gallery does have several paintings by the Impressionist Pierre Auguste Renoir in its permanent collection of over 75,000 items. More than 30,000 of these objects are displayed online in downloadable form, including [five by Renoir](https://www.ngv.vic.gov.au/explore/collection/artist/1194/). However, none shows "a river and a tree-shaded street beside it, with white houses and shops". Of course, even now, museums do not usually post images of every item in their collections, and Nevil Shute's Renoir could well be hanging on a gallery wall in full view. So this question is chiefly for Australians who have visited the National Gallery: What is the name of this painting, if in fact it exists?

Comment: "*a painting of a river and a tree-shaded street beside it, with white houses and shops, very French and very colorful*" described about 30% of Renoir's creative output

Comment: https://content.ngv.vic.gov.au/retrieve.php?size=1280&type=image&vernonID=4191 - Often mixed up with Renoir

Comment: Renoir's [Cagnes Landscape](http://www.pierreaugusterenoir.net/Cagnes%20Landscape%20Pierre-Auguste%20Renoir.jpg) series fits the description nicely. There were about ten of them, so it's certainly possible that the gallery in Victoria had one.

Comment: Terraces at Cagnes also matches the description, but it's not especially colourful; https://www.wikiart.org/en/pierre-auguste-renoir/terraces-at-cagnes-1905

Comment: WikiArt has images of [nearly 1400 pieces of art by Renoir](https://www.wikiart.org/en/pierre-auguste-renoir/all-works#!#filterName:all-paintings-chronologically,resultType:masonry). (I know it says 1412, but there are duplicates.) Renoir doesn't often show a river _and_ a road (but not a bridge).  Closest I could find were [this one](https://www.wikiart.org/en/pierre-auguste-renoir/landscape-in-normandy-1895) and [this one](https://www.wikiart.org/en/pierre-auguste-renoir/the-banks-of-the-seine-1875).

Comment: The Banks of the Seine at Bougival is apparently in a private collection in Australia...; https://www.pierre-auguste-renoir.org/thumbnail/79000/79445/mini_small/The-Banks-Of-The-Seine-Bougival.jpg?ts=1459229076

Comment: The Village (at Essoyes) has a river, tree-lined road and visible houses and shops; https://uploads4.wikiart.org/images/pierre-auguste-renoir/the-village.jpg!Large.jpg

Comment: @DavidW - There's another 600 [here](https://www.pierre-auguste-renoir.org/the-complete-works.html), representing pretty much every work that isn't lost or in (secretive)  private hands

Comment: @Valorum Those are the exact 2 I found as well. :)  GM and all that...

Comment: If we're looking for works in the NGV collection that are close there's [this one by Pissarro](https://www.ngv.vic.gov.au/explore/collection/work/4258/).

Comment: Wow. Thanks, all! I didn't think this question would stimulate much interest, but am gratified to see that it struck a chord with you. OK. On rereading the passage from _On the Beach_, I now realize that Shute didn't actually say the landscape was by Renoir, though it would have been hung nearby, so presumably it was by a French impressionist. Renoir apparently didn't paint a lot of landscapes. So suggestions of landscapes matching the description, but by other painters, already held by the NGV when Shute finished his book in 1957, are fair game. The Pisarro may fit the bill.

Comment: Maybe one or more of these comments can be turned into answers...

Comment: OK, Australia has had time to weigh in and there is no definite answer. I think DavidW's answer may be the closest we can get to -- of a painting that answers the requirements and was definitely owned by the National Gallery when Shute could have seen it. So, DavidW, if you want to convert this into a "We can't know for sure but..." answer, we can reach closure. Sort of.

Comment: I've emailed the Gallery staff. Hopefully they can shed some light

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are umpteen Renoir pictures that meet the broad description (see below), but none that are known to be held by the National Gallery of Victoria.

For the record, Shute lived in Victoria, so it's highly likely that he was describing an *actual* piece of artwork, rather than having seen one of the pictures below (which are currently in collections outside of Australia) in a book of art or elsewhere.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This picture, *The Banks of the Seine Bougival*, is in Australia, but held in a private collection. It may have been shown at the National at some point.

[image]

---

That all being said, the picture isn't specifically described as being a Renoir, merely that it's *found in a collection of French art that includes Renoirs*.

> They went and found ***the French art***, and he stood for some time before a painting of a river and a tree-shaded street beside it

They could, for example, be describing Claude Monet's *Vetheuil*, which was (and still is) in the French collection held by the National Gallery of Victoria.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for spending so much time and effort to research this question. I appreciate it. I think this is as close as we can reasonably get to an answer based on publicly available information.